# Finding method declaration that have no definition

Tags: c++, gcc

I'm in the process of cleaning up some code of mine that was quite tricky to write. I sometimes introduced methods in a class but later deleted it again because through the process it was not needed any more. However, I often just delete the definition in the .cpp and leave the declaration in the .h file.

I like to find such empty declarations. Is there a switch that e.g. gcc throws a warning? Am I alone with this problem?

Answer (score 0):

If you suspect a method declaration isn't used, comment it out and see if everything still compiles. Repeat until closure.

Comment: This isn't really a scalable solution.

Answer (score -1):

use `g++ -Wall`

The error message will be in the pattern of:

`undefined reference to SomeClassnameYouHave::foo()'`

Comment: Not really. The OP is asking for a warning and this is an *error* that will occur only if the undefined method is called.